# Terminate a running python program only when the system shuts down

Tags: python

Is there anyway to terminate a python program only when the user shutsdown the system?
I want to include the condition in the while loop so that it keeps on looping till the system shutsdown.
Also is there a way to start the program automatically on booting the system?

Comment: Shutdown closes all processes, no?

Comment: yes. and is there a way that i can run the program immediately on booting the system?

Comment: That's a different question, so you could [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Also see [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Thank u mate. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
while True :
    pass  # do something
```

This loop will be terminated when the system shuts down.

Comment: yes i used the same argument for while. does it work? and is there any way to start the program on booting the system?

Comment: yes i was using it but not sure about running the program automatically on boot

Comment: @JOKER you may add `@boot` or `@reboot` to your `crontab` to make sure it restarts

Answer (score 2):

Convert your python app to linux service is much better than white true only